# C#: Creating SystemInfo dialog similar to Visual Studio Help | System Info

Tags: c#

Within Visual Studio, if you click on Help | About Microsoft Visual Studio | System Info, you get a tree view with system info parameters.

I am looking at the `System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher` class to create a similar dialog but is there a .NET API one can call to bring up a similar window with such info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a one-liner:

```
    private void SysInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msinfo32.exe");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) control?

Comment: Yes, that's what he mentioned in his question.